# I and B tags should be styled like EM and STRONG on mobile (beta site CSS)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

Beta sites contain the following CSS:

```
  b,strong{font-weight:bold;}i,em{font-style:italic;}
```

For people using the non-mobile interface, it appears that the B and STRONG tags can be used more or less interchangeably, and that the same is true for I and EM.  However, in the mobile site CSS, only the latter of each pair is styled—only EM and STRONG work.

### If you use the B or I tags they *silently fail* for users on the mobile site.

This wouldn't be a problem if people didn't use these tags, but they do.  Why?

Because of a long-standing bug, the Markdown engine doesn't handle bold or italics correctly with [Chinese](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/bold-tag-not-applied-to-chinese-words-correctly) or [Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120/issues-with-bolding), and users often insert HTML as a workaround.  But while Markdown turns stars into EM and STRONG tags, users adding HTML by hand [often assume they can use the B and I tags instead](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/revisions/0f1da5c0-6526-4c0f-9cea-82275d0cfe68/view-source).  After all, they're easier to type and it *looks* like they work!

#### *And since it appears to work on the full site, these users may never know there's a problem on mobile.*

This problem doesn't just come up on Chinese and Japanese, either.  People don't just use HTML as a workaround—they use it as a first resort.  Over on ELL meta, [a user recently argued](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/996/minor-recurring-formatting-errors-and-how-to-avoid-them#comment2279_997) that the I tag is to be preferred to EM.  And it's easy to find [real examples of posts on ELL using those tags](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/495/230).  In fact, [even Stack Exchange employees recommend using the B and I tags.](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/59)

---

Take a look at these screen shots:

1. Full site:

   > [image: full site screen shot]
2. Mobile site:

   > [image: mobile site screen shot]

You can see this for yourself over on the [Japanese meta](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1091/b-and-i-tags-should-be-styled-like-strong-and-em-on-the-mobile-site), if you like.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't matter which browser you use.  Click back and forth between the full and mobile sites to see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be available in the next deployment (`rev 2251` on meta and `rev 1609` on the network).